# Unable to get property listing in wordpress rental as JSON

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I have a wordpress rental site that lists available property for reservation.
I am trying to get the JSON data for property listing in my WordPress rental site.

When i bought the theme it has built-in Property listing.

I tried WP REST API and JSON API but both plugins return Site's posts,comments,author and other things not related to the property.

Should i install a plugin to get the property listing data as JSON?

Any suggestions please?